# PHP File downloads if Nginx deny rule enabled

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've had an Nginx server running for over a year with no issues, it serves HTML and PHP files just fine for the Wordpress sites on it. Recently there was some brute force attacks on the wp-login.php so I decided to limit access to these areas by IP using Nginx's deny all rules.

I've implemented the rule below and IP's not in the list get a 403 as expected but allowed IPs are served a downloaded wp-login.php file instead of the site page.

Here is the domain rules:

```
server { 
   listen      10.99.0.20:8080;
   server_name  www.example.com;
   root /home/www.example.com/public_html;
   index index.html index.htm index.php;
   include conf.d/whitelisted.conf;
   include conf.d/wp/restrictions.conf;
   include conf.d/wp/wordpress.conf;
 }
```

The whitelisted.conf includes a load of whitelisted IP's, I won't post the list but it ends:

```
   ...
   allow 1.2.3.4;

   # DROP THE WORLD #
   deny all;
```

The restrictions.conf to which I've added the new deny rule (last) is:

```
# Global restrictions configuration file.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.
location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
}

# Block PHP files in uploads, content, and includes directory.
location ~* /(?:uploads|files|wp-content|wp-includes)/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

 # location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
                allow 1.2.3.4
                deny all;
 }
```

The wordpress.conf file is:

```
 # WordPress single site rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.   (ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
   access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Block PHP files in uploads directory.
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

# Block PHP files in content directory.
location ~* /wp-content/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

# Block PHP files in includes directory.
location ~* /wp-includes/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

# Block PHP files in uploads, content, and includes directory.
location ~* /(?:uploads|files|wp-content|wp-includes)/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    return 404;
  }
  # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works     with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)

  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
  fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
  fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 18000;  
}
```

...and finally the fastcgi_params is:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

Appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration, PHP files are processed by the following block:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 18000;  
}
```

By adding `location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) { ... }` you are diverting those URIs to be processed as static files.

One solution is to duplicate all of the required FastCGI statements into the new location, so that `nginx` processes the URI as a PHP file, for example:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
    allow 1.2.3.4
    deny all;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```